# Does it help uploading s QGIS minidump file when reporting a bug?

Tags: qgis, error, windows, minidump

Is it helpful for the developers to upload the minidump file (.dmp) at hub.qgis.org when QGIS is crashing?

[image]

Comment: Does a minidump file contain any personal data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really - the minidump format is very difficult to extract anything meaningful out of. In my experience (as a member of the core QGIS development team) none of the team use these dump files for bug fixing. Instead of the dump file, a step-by-step description of a reliable way to reproduce the crash is greatly preferred (including attaching any required data files needed to reproduce it).

Comment: I agree with ndawson. The company I'm working for makes use of paid professional QGIS Support and the minidump-analysis did not help much to find the program crash reasons. What helped us more was a QGIS-install with debug output.

Comment: QGIS crashes quite often for no apparent reason. What's the best way to report these crashes? QGIS is installed on several Win7 computers in the company I'm working for .

Comment: We had the best success with using the --noplugin option to check if a plugin caused the crash. If plugins didn't cause the error we had some TeamViewer sessions with a QGIS-Developer who reproduced the error and analysed the debug output of QGIS in DebugView